# Gatsby - WebpackError: Invariant Violation error with apolloClient

Tags: typescript, webpack, gatsby, apollo, react-apollo

I just converted a Gatsby project to Typescript and now cannot run the dev server because of this error:

```
There was an error compiling the html.js component for the development server.

See our docs page on debugging HTML builds for help https://gatsby.dev/debug-html Invariant Violation:


  10 |     function InvariantError(message) {
  11 |         if (message === void 0) { message = genericMessage; }
> 12 |         var _this = _super.call(this, typeof message === "number"
     | ^
  13 |             ? genericMessage + ": " + message + " (see https://github.com/apollographql/invariant-packages)"
  14 |             : message) || this;
  15 |         _this.framesToPop = 1;


  WebpackError: Invariant Violation:
  
  - invariant.esm.js:12 
    node_modules/ts-invariant/lib/invariant.esm.js:12:1
  
  - checkFetcher.js:4 
    node_modules/@apollo/client/link/http/checkFetcher.js:4:77
  
  - createHttpLink.js:15 
    node_modules/@apollo/client/link/http/createHttpLink.js:15:17
  
  - apolloClient.ts:3 
    src/utils/apolloClient.ts:3:36
```

Here's my apolloClient.ts with various experiments:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, createHttpLink } from '@apollo/client'

export const link = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'https://48p1r2roz4.sse.codesandbox.io'
})

export const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'https://48p1r2roz4.sse.codesandbox.io',
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
})

// export const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
//   link,
//   //uri: process.env.GATSBY_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
//   cache: new InMemoryCache()
// })
```

Googling suggest two things:

1. a webpack invariant error can occur with a mix of import/require. That is prob not the issue - if I replace the file with:

```
export const apolloClient = ''
```

Things go fine.

I have tried a variety of link/url config etc... No go.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well it appears that something is swallowing the error descriptions. Looking at the source of checkFetcher it's clear that its not finding `fetch` even though it's installed (isomorphic-fetch) - in production I may have gotten error "22" but for some reason the nice provided message does not appear in my console.

```
import { InvariantError } from 'ts-invariant';
export var checkFetcher = function (fetcher) {
    if (!fetcher && typeof fetch === 'undefined') {
        throw process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? new InvariantError(22) : new InvariantError("\n\"fetch\" has not been found globally and no fetcher has been configured. To fix this, install a fetch package (like https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-fetch), instantiate the fetcher, and pass it into your HttpLink constructor. For example:\n\nimport fetch from 'cross-fetch';\nimport { ApolloClient, HttpLink } from '@apollo/client';\nconst client = new ApolloClient({\n  link: new HttpLink({ uri: '/graphql', fetch })\n});\n    ");
    }
};
//# sourceMappingURL=checkFetcher.js.map
```

The solution is to explicitly pass fetch to apolloConfig:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, createHttpLink } from '@apollo/client'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'

export const link = createHttpLink({
  fetch,
  uri: process.env.GATSBY_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT
})

export const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link
})
```

Also it has nothing to do with Webpack. Looks like the error propagated misleadingly.

Comment: Bless your heart. Exactly this.